# Error can't receive .local data in another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am newbie coder and i am triying to save the info of user in res.locals, but when i try to get it in another js file, doasnt reseive de info...

```js
//root.js

var router_app =require('./modulos/rutas');


web.post('/login',function(entra,sale){ 

  sale.locals = {user : 'Some Text'};
  console.log(sale.locals.user);
  sale.redirect('/dashboard');
  });
  
  ///this show "Some Text"
  
web.use('/dashboard',router_app);
```

But when i try to get the info in another file, cant get the info of locals

```js
//  ./modulos/rutas.js

var router =  express.Router();

router.get('/',(entra,sale)=>{

  console.log("[rutas.js]Respuesta local en console:        "+sale.locals.user);

});
```

This Show me the error:

```
[root.js]Mostrando Locales [object Object]
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

What it mean "Primitive Value"?

Comment: primitive value itself means a data that is not an object

Comment: Instead of router.get('/'... can u please try router.get('/login'...

Comment: Sorry, i didnt paste the code correctly... I just modified it